# In app - from paid to gratis

Tags: in-app-purchase, iad

i ha ve a question, i have from 1 year a paid app on app store, now i want to convert the app to gratis app with iAd and possibility to remove iAd with in-app purchase...the problem is that I want to disable iAd for who have buy the app.

There is a way for do this?